# Create a modules with models in python

Tags: python, django

I have a rather strange problem, I wanted to make a whole module of models but django does not recognize that module with models
For example:
[image]

I created this module in which I made a folder models
I also made an init py in which I import the model but nothing happens to me
How should I proceed in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `models.py` file, and don't forget to add imports into `botlogic/models/__init__.py`.